# ASP.NET Relation between two tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, has-many

I'm new in Asp.Net and Entity Framework and i have a little issue.

I know u can help me , because its simple and i only know how to do it in PHP XD

I Have 2 models

```
 public class Suppliers
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ID_Guard { get; set; }

    public string Supplier{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime Enter { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime Exit { get; set; }

    public virtual Guard Guard { get; set; }
}



public class Guard
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Suppliers> Suppliers{ get; set; }

}
```

controller

```
public class SuppliersController : Controller
{
    private SuppliersContext db = new SuppliersContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Suppliers.ToList());
    }
}
```

And i wanna pass to the view the 2 table data and relate it

When i go to index show me all the `suppliers` data and show the Guard name( the person who registered the supplier enter and exit)

Well its solved

```
 var results = from c in db.Suppliers
                      join cn in db.Guard on c.ID_Guard equals cn.ID

                      where (c.ID_Guard == cn.ID)
                      select new Models.MyViewModel{ Name= cn.Name, ID = c.ID, Supplier=c.Supplier, Description=c.Description, Enter=c.Enter, Exit=c.Exit};
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the below code it works and seems same like yours also i added the link hope you find It helpful

```
 public class Product
{
    public Product() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}


public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
     /////view model///
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product Category")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
```

}

follow the below tutorial
[relationship model](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

for basic join use below query

```
var dealercontacts = from contact in table1
                 join table2 in table2 on contact.Id equals another.ID
                 select contact;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, where i should put that aproachs? on controller right? And at view i dont need to use @model?

Comment: It gave me an error on " a.values,c.values" 
Error CS1922 Cannot initialize type 'MyViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: And give me error " Context.Guard" it saying doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: Well it worked for me , but still dont know how i can show in my index view

Comment: i can't make an sqlquery to join the two tables where Suppliers.ID_Guard=Guard.ID

Comment: List<Suppliers> suppliersList = new List<Suppliers>().ToList();
            List<Guard> guardList= new List<Guard>().ToList();
            var query = from Suppliers in suppliersList
                                 join Guard in guardList on Suppliers.ID_Guard equals Guard.ID
                                 select Suppliers;                                                   return View(dealercontacts.ToList());

Comment: and retrieve me the error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Teste.Suppliers]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Teste.Models.MyViewModel]'.

Comment: Well i dont know how but i did it   var results = from c in db.Suppliers
                          join cn in db.Guard on c.ID_Guard equals cn.ID
            
                          where (c.ID_Guard == cn.ID)
                          select new Models.MyViewModel{ Name= cn.Name, ID = c.ID, Supplier=c.Supplier, Description=c.Description, Enter=c.Enter, Exit=c.Exit};